# What happens if we lose voluntary control of our breathing?

Tags: neuroscience, physiology, breathing

Breathing can be controlled voluntarily, even though it is automatic. What happens if a person loses voluntary control of their breathing? How much would it effect day-to-day life? What are its effects on exercise?

Comment: What specific problem are you trying to solve. broad hypotheticals are generally off topic. to start with how did they lose voluntary control.

Comment: Some sort of surgery that accidentally cut the "voluntary-control-nerve?"

Comment: That would entail severing quite a few nerves. This is only likely to happen in the case of a broken neck or something else of great severity - there would be issues with breathing *at all*, let alone voluntarily. Could you be a bit more specific about what it is you're trying to explore, and with what purpose?

Comment: It's basically the same purpose as that of Randall Munroe's *What If* book.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with that. Could you [edit] the question to add details from the book which would be relevant, as comments are not intended to last. You're perhaps referring to some sort of brain-surgery? Might not [psychology.se] be a better place to ask about the consequences of that? You'd need to be clearer about what's going on in the story.

Comment: To quote Munroe, it is "thoroughly answer[ing] a stupid question can take you to some pretty interesting places"

Comment: I'm sure that's true. There are obvious things like difficulty eating and speaking - what have your prior researches into the topic shown you?

Comment: As for the Psychology & Neuroscience thing, I don't think it is worth creating an account on a new site for this question.

Comment: I know about the speaking thing, but I think that the body would involuntarily prevent choking while eating...

Comment: Maybe, it'd depend on the specifics of the lesion/malfunction.

Comment: It literally ttakes two clicks of a mouse to create a new account there......

Comment: I know, but there are the hurdles of adapting to handle the (slightly different) community of the new site...